# Using graphs to solve equations

Tags: problem-solving

After drawing the graph of $y=2x^2-3x-1$, I have to draw the graph of $2x^2-3x=0$, I know you have to rearrange to get the original equation but if there are no constants then how am I suppose to rearrange for the original and find what $y$ equals to then find the solutions of the graph?

Comment: If you are drawing a graph, it will require plotting some points.  If you are plotting a continuous function, drawing the graph can help visualize where it crosses the $x$-axis, i.e. see roughly where the roots are located.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

if $2x^2-3x=0$, then $y=-1$ , so you will look for intersection of your graph with the horizontal line whose equation is $y=-1$.